# Why does printf generate a garbage value when used in conjunction with a long type and a new line?

Tags: c, printf, getchar

I'm currently going through the book for C Programming Language, 2nd edition, and came across an example which produced a strange result. I have a simple C program which prints the number of characters that a user inputs through the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    long nc;

    nc = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            continue;
        }

        ++nc;
    }

    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Strangely enough, when I run the program, provide "abc" as input and then send the EOF character via ctrl+d

I get the following result: `3D`

The number 3 in the result makes sense because I entered 3 characters, but I'm curious as to what the letter D represents. Would it be considered a garbage value because the string is missing a null terminator `\0`?

Comment: It’s possible your terminal decided to echo back `^D` when you pressed Ctrl+D and the `3` got written over it. Does it still happen if you provide the input with a pipe like `echo 123 | ./program`, or type more than 9 characters?

Comment: that's interesting! nop, it doesn't happen when we pipe it with `echo 123 | ./program`. it's probably the command `^D` causing it.

it also doesn't happen if we type more than 9 characters

input: abcdefghij 
output: 10

Comment: i'm trying to figure out an explanation because the behaviour doesn't seem to be consistent. for the input `abcdefghij`, I would expect the terminal to echo back `^D` and get the output `10D`

Comment: `3` overwrites `^`. `10` overwrites `^D`. Which OS are you using? Are you pressing Ctrl+D at the start of a line?

Comment: that makes sense! thanks! i'm using macOS Big Sur and pressing ctrl+d at the start of the line

Comment: Hm, weird. Are you using the built-in Terminal.app, or iTerm2, or…? Does it still happen if you open a fresh tab and run the program there?

Comment: I'm currently using the built-in Terminal.app and yes it still happens when I run the program in a brand new zsh session

Comment: You can see things more clearly if you change the printf to `printf("\n%ld\n", nc);`. In other words, add a newline `\n` at the beginning of the format string.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for that! yes i see ^D on its own line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the following result: 3D

This is what happened:

- You entered `abc` and then hit the return key.
- You pushed Ctrl-D and the terminal echoed it as `^D`.
- Your program printed `3` (the number of non-newline characters input), overwritting the `^` character.
- Your program printed a new line `\n`, so you got the output `3D`.

The terminal you are using is echoing control characters in `^` notation.

You don't use any string array to accumulate characters, so it's impossible to lack a `\0` string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments suggested by @Ry- and @user3386109, the `^D` is being overwritten by the actual result and we end up with the output 3D.

3 overwrites ^ and D is not overwritten so it remains and we get the result `3D`